# Can pokemon run while taking a picture?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was just wondering if a pokemon could run away while taking a photo?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it cannot. The only time a pokemon can flee from you is after it pops out of a pokeball.

Source: Personal Experience